# Is it possible to get the nested json output in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, marklogic

I am using MarkLogic `8.0-6.3`

I came across a scenario where I need nested JSON output in SPARQL.

For example there are multiple same predicates for an IRI, in the result I want the multiple values in array not as a whole triple.

for example:

Assume triples:

```
@prefix p0: <http://www.mla.com/term/> .
p0:7 <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#narrower> p0:768 ,
                                                    p0:769 ,
                                                    p0:770 ,
                                                    p0:771 .
```

SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX skos-mla: <http://www.mlacustom.com#>
PREFIX term: <http://www.mla.com/term/>

select ?iri ?o {   
    graph<thesaurus-term>{         
        bind(term:7 as ?iri)
        term:7 skos:narrower ?o .
    }
}
```

the above query will return the 4 triples as output.

What I want is it should just return me a single json structure like

```
{
    "iri": "http://www.mla.com/term/7",
    "narrowers": ["http://www.mla.com/term/768", "http://www.mla.com/term/769", "http://www.mla.com/term/770", "http://www.mla.com/term/771"]
}
```

Above JSON is just to explain the problem.
In actual I would need a more complex json structure like instead of string array I need an array of json objects.

I know that I can read the response and recreate the whole json in any format  but it has performance impacts.

Answer (score 3):

In recent versions of MarkLogic 9, the Optic API can support this requirement:

1. Use the [`op.fromSPARQL()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/op.fromSPARQL) accessor to project columns of values from the triples.
2. Chain a `select()` call using [`op.jsonObject()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/op.jsonObject) to collect the values as properties of objects.
3. Chain a `groupBy()` call using [`op.arrayAggregate()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/op.arrayAggregate) to aggregate the objects in an array.
4. Chain a `result()` call to get the output.

For more information, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/op.jsonObject

and:

http://docs.marklogic.com/op.arrayAggregate

Hoping that helps,